# Get error messages from Zend_Form and response as json

Tags: php, ajax, json, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to get error messages from Zend_Form and response as json. What is the best practice of getting Zend_Form errors and replying as json?

```
<?

class SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

        $form = new Application_SomeForm();
        if ($form->isValid( $this->getRequest()->getPost() )) {
            //do something here
        }       
        $this->_helper->json($form->getErrorMessages());

    }

}
```

I can't get errors via `$form->getErrorMessages()`, but errors are present if tested `print_r($form->gerErrors())`

```
Array
(
    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => isEmpty
        )

    [password] => Array
        (
            [0] => isEmpty
        )

    [foreign] => Array
        (
        )

    [login] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

So, my questions are:

**a) How to get all error messages for form?**

**b) Is there any Json Wrapper for resposning ajax submitted forms? For example `$jsonResponse->setErrorStatus()->addFormErrors($form)`**

Comment: Have you tried `getMessages()`? I think this is the method you'd like to use to get human-friendly error messages.

Comment: @bububaba, yes I've tried, but it returns empty array, but `$form->getErrors()` returns array with validation codes (like `isEmpty`) (see above).

Comment: You wrote you've tried `getErrorMessages` and `getErrors`, but `getMessages` is a different beast altogether, that's why I'm asking whether you've tried it. `getErrors` returns codes, `getErrorMessages` returns registered custom error messages (seems probable you have none), while `getMessages` returns the actual human-friendly error messages. I'm posting this as an answer, do check it out :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried `getMessages`? I think this is the method you'd like to use to get human-friendly error messages.

You wrote you've tried `getErrorMessages` and `getErrors`, but `getMessages` is a different beast altogether, that's why I'm asking whether you've tried it.

`getErrors` returns codes, `getErrorMessages` returns registered custom error messages (seems probable you have none), while `getMessages` returns the actual human-friendly error messages.